# Why doesn't my app route to it's custom page? nextjs

Tags: next.js

I have a `nextjs` app.  My pages folder looks like this

```
pages
  games
  game
```

I have a route in my `server.js` that looks like this:

```
server.get('/games/:gameId', (req, res) => {
  const { gameId } = req.params

  app.render(req, res, 'game', { gameId })
})
```

I have also tried `app.render(req, res, '/game', { gameId })`, but that didn't work either.

I am wanting to route to `game.js` when `/games/1` is hit.  The app routes fine to `/games`, but I can't route to the single game `/games/1`.  I get the `nextjs` `404`.  What am I missing?  How does `nextjs` route in situations like this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code could look like:

```
server.get('/games/:gameId', (req, res) => {
  app.render(req, res, '/game', { ...req.query, ...req.params })
})
```

See how your own code is missing the leading slash in front of `game`?

`app.render` third parameter should be the full path of the route living in the `pages` directory.

The fourth parameter can be generically set to an aggregation of both `req.query` and `req.params`, to have both your `gameId` param as well as the query parameters transmitted to your Next.js code.